# ArcPy scripts input/output

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, parameters

I have an ArcPy script, which I use with ArcGIS Pro. I use one feature class as input_feature, do some calculations and write results in another feature class (output_feature).

Is it possible to use the the same feature class as input and output? I want to write my calculation in the same feaure class, which was the input.

Comment: Yes it is possible, but you need to share your script. Edit your question and include it.

Comment: While update is possible in some contexts, the general paradigm that utilizes inputs and outputs doesn't permit the output to replace the input (since the output must not previously exist, and deleting it first then corrupts the input). You need to provide specifics on what you're attempting for a specific answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible.

The easiest way to understand this pattern is to create a new model and use a tool like **Calculate Field** inside it. This tool **updates** the data, thus it does not create a new output featureclass. When you drag this tool into the model, you'll see it pre-populates an output. However, when you use the tool, you don't ever set an output parameter. This output is considered a **derived parameter**, meaning the tool figures out what it should be.

In your case, it's unknown if you need to follow the pattern exactly. If you're doing something relatively simple like calculating a field, and the tool has been designed to work inside ArcMap or ArcGIS Pro, you can create it using just an **input parameter**. You don't need to worry about adding a derived output parameter because the layer is already in your map. Adding the derived output would be useful in chaining the tool you're making  to other tools (think using your tool in ModelBuilder) or if you're working against a featureclass *not* in the map, but you want the tool to add it to the map after it finishes.

Search for derived in the [using tools in Python](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/geoprocessing_and_python/using-tools-in-python.htm) for more information.

Alternatively, if I'm misunderstood your question and you're asking about this workflow entirely from inside a script (not operating inside ArcGIS Pro), its even easier. See the following code example, you just make use of the same variable pointing to your featureclass. If a tool only *updates* the data, like both Add Field and Calculate Field, then just keep using the same variable.

```
inFeatures = r"c:\temp\foo.gdb\myFC"
fieldName = "RndValue"
expression = "random.randint(0, 10)"
code_block = "import random"
 
# Execute AddField
arcpy.AddField_management(inFeatures, fieldName, "LONG")
 
# Execute CalculateField 
arcpy.CalculateField_management(inFeatures, fieldName, expression, "PYTHON3", 
                                code_block)
```